# Selection group field in Crystal

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

in header group 1 i have a tasks.location, in the result i get 2 locations that i want to add up in 1 existing location. is there a way to do this ?

something like this ?

if {TASKS.LOCATION} is "210-1" then add to "210"

Comment: in referring to what field you want to add the 2 locations?

Comment: Header text group#1: [Name group #1:TASKS.LOCATION] [Sum of TASKS.WO_NUM]                                                  Details: [TASKS.WorkOrderStatusId]                                   then in the result i want the location with number of workorders added up if the location number is the same.

Answer (score 0):

If the location is same then you want to add the workorders... then you can do the following:

1. Group by location first.
2. Place the `workorders` in detail and take summary by using `Insert Summary`

Let me know if this not you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Group on a formula field that extracts the 'integer' value, rather than the `TASKS.LOCATION` field:

```
// {@LOCATION}
Split( {TASKS.LOCATION}, "-" )[1]
```